# In Python 3, best way to open an image stored in a list as a file object?

Tags: image, python-3.x, qr-code, python-imaging-library

Using python 3.4 in linux and windows, I'm trying to create qr code images from a list of string objects. I don't want to just store the image as a file because the list of strings may change frequently. I want to then tile all the objects and display the resulting image on screen for the user to scan with a barcode scanner. For the user to know which code to scan I need to add some text to the qr code image.

I can create the list of image objects correctly and they are in a list and calling .show on these objects displays them properly but I don't know how to treat these objects as a file object to open them. The object that is given to the open function, (`img_list[0]` in my case), in my `add_text_to_img` needs to support `read`, `seek` and `tell` methods. When I try this as is I get an attribute error. I've tried BytesIO and StringIO but I get an error message that Image.open does not support buffer interface.  Maybe I am not doing that part correctly.

I'm sure there are several ways to do this, but what is the best way to open in memory objects as a file object?

```
from io import BytesIO
import qrcode
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image

def make_qr_image_list(code_list):
    """

    :param code_list:   a list of string objects to encode into QR code image
    :return:            a list of image or some type of other data objects
    """
    img_list = []
    for item in code_list:
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(
                            version=None,
                            error_correction=qrcode.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
                            box_size=4,
                            border=10
                            )
        qr.add_data(item)
        qr_image = qr.make_image(fit=True)
        img_list.append(qr_image)

    return img_list

def add_text_to_img(text_list, img_list):
    """
    While I was working on this, I am only saving the first image. Once
    it's working, I'll save the rest of the images to a list.
    :param text_list:   a list of strings to add to the corresponding image.
    :param img_list:    the list containing the images already created from
                        the text_list
    :return:
    """
    base = Image.open(img_list[0])
    # img = Image.frombytes(mode='P', size=(164,164), data=img_list[0])
    text_img = Image.new('RGBA', base.size, (255,255,255,0))

    font    = ImageFont.truetype('sans-serif.ttf', 10)
    draw    = ImageDraw.Draw(text_img)
    draw.text((0,-20),text_list[0], (0,0,255,128), font=font)
    #  include some method to save the images after the text
    #  has been added here. Shouldn't actually save to a file.
    #  Should be saved to memory/img_list
    output = Image.alpha_composite(base,text_img)
    output.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list   = ['AlGaN','n-AlGaN','p-AlGaN','MQW','LED AlN-AlGaN']
    image_list  = make_qr_image_list(test_list)
    add_text_to_img(test_list, image_list)
    im          = image_list[0]
    im.save('/my_save_path/test_image.png')
    im.show()
```

Edit: I've been using python for about a year and I feel like this is a pretty common thing to do but I'm not even sure that I'm looking up/searching for the right terms. What topics would you search for to answer this? If anyone can post a link or two to what I need to read up on regarding this, that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *already* have `PIL` image objects; `qr.make_image()` returns the (a wrapper around) the right type of object and you do not need to open them again.

As such, all you need to do is:

```
base = img_list[0]
```

and go from there.

You do need to match image modes when compositing; QR codes are black-and-white images (mode 1), so either convert that or use the same mode in your `text_img` image object. The `Image.alpha_composite()` operation does require that both images have an alpha channel. Converting the base is easy:

```
base = img_list[0].convert('RGBA')
```

Comment: Well, I swear that was the first thing I tried but I must have had a problem elsewhere. I have it working now. Marked as answer and many thanks!